# requestAnimationFrame with clearAnimationFrame on scroll event

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe, cancelanimationframe

There are so many questions about JavaScript's `requestAnimationFrame` already and (I think) I understand the concept but is there any performance difference between with and without `cancelAnimationFrame` in this context?

```
// Setup a timer
var timeout;

// Listen for resize events
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {

    console.log( 'no debounce' );

    // Cancel last animation, if there's one
    if (timeout) {
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(timeout);
    }

    // Setup the new requestAnimationFrame()
    timeout = window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {

        // Run our scroll functions
        console.log( 'debounced' );

    });

}, false);
```

without `cancelAnimationFrame`:

```
// Setup a timer
var timeout;

// Listen for resize events
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {

    console.log( 'no debounce' );


    // Setup the new requestAnimationFrame()
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {

        // Run our scroll functions
        console.log( 'debounced' );

    });

}, false);
```

I get the same result on each code.

But I want to know what happens if I don't cancel the animation frame. Does requested function get stacked somewhere in memory or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var isRafLogged = false;

function rafCb(now) {
  if (isRafLogged) {
    console.log('rAF callback executed at: ', now, 'ms');
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(rafCb);
}

function onWindowScroll() {
  // when in scroll, log aforescheduled rAF() only when in scroll
  isRafLogged = true;
  const now = performance.now();

  console.log('scroll callback executed at: ', now, 'ms');

  // when out of scroll, stop logging the rAF
  setTimeout(function() {
    isRafLogged = false;
  });
}

requestAnimationFrame(rafCb);

window.addEventListener('scroll', onWindowScroll);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 10000px;
}

p {
  font-size: 200px;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}
```

```html
<p>.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................</p>
```

If we schedule a continuous separate `requestAnimationFrame` loop while we `scroll`, we will clearly see that `rAF` and `scroll` callbacks are happening 
at max once per [VSync event](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/92/vertical-sync-vsync).

Thus returning to your main question

> is there any performance difference between with and without cancelAnimationFrame in this context ?

Generally no, because your `requestAnimationFrame()` call is blocking the next `scroll` callback, and you cannot have more scroll callbacks executed than your requested frame callback, there is a 1 to 1 correlation, since they both happen at max every frame render.

> But I want to know what happens if I don't cancel the animation frame. Does requested function get stacked somewhere in memory or something?

All requested animation frame callbacks are stacked in the internal pool of [callbacks](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/modules/xr/xr_frame_request_callback_collection.cc?g=0&l=23), that get flushed before the nearest Vsync event. So yes technically the only way to remove the scheduled callbacks is `cancelAnimationFrame()`, but again it's not relevant in your case since your `requestAnimationFrame()` callback is happening at the "same" time with window `scroll` callback.

Hope it makes sense.